# How to list only user provided file names from the directory in C?

Tags: c, list, directory

I know how to printf all files from the directory,but how i find one specific file in that directory using name provided earlier by user?

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char a,b;
    printf("Path:(eg.c:/): ");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    d = opendir (&a);
    if (d)
    {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dir->d_name);
        }
        closedir(d);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want.  You want the input to be a directory name and a list of files, and then you want to print only the values in the given list that are in the directory?

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between what you want, and printing out what the user typed *without* looking at the directory?

Comment: I just wanna to list one file from path, path and filename is provided by user.

Comment: You are really not explaining yourself clearly. If the user has given you the path and file name and you want to print that path and file name then why don't you just print what the user has entered? But clearly you want some other processing/logic but you are not clearly explaining what that is.

Comment: `char a; scanf("%s",&a);`. That isn't correct. `%s` requires a pointer to a buffer that can store the full input string. You have given a buffer containing only one byte. Since a string needs a null terminator it means it can only store an empty string. If the user enters anything at all the result is a buffer overflow.

Comment: I don't wanna to printf the name of the file,I wanna to find that file in the specific directory.

Comment: Ok, so user enters a directory name and a file name. Then you want to search the directory and if it contains the file name you want to print the file name. And if it doesn't contain the file you want to print nothing? Is that it?

Comment: Yes,that's exactly what i want

Comment: So just use `strcmp` to compare the entered name and `dir->d_name`. Also need to check that `dir->d_type == DT_REG`. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Unfortunately not, Windows

Comment: My Mistake.  They are [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960605(v%3Dmsdn.10)) and [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960609(v%3Dmsdn.10)).

Comment: I would like to know how to implement this in my code because I have never used these functions.

Comment: `dirent.h` is specific to UNIX/Linux flavers of operating systems.  If you are using Windows, this does not apply.  Also this statement:  `printf("Path:(eg.c:/): ");`, where you are evidently providing some instructions for user input, is not right for Windows, it should be "c:\\".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments:
*I would like to know how to implement this in my code because I have never used these functions*.

Since you are using Windows,  [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960605(v%3Dmsdn.10)) and [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms960609(v%3Dmsdn.10)) can be used to search a directory for a list of [filespecs](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=filespec), from there you can simply use `strstr` to isolate the file you need by comparing the search result with your user's desired filename.

Here is an example that can be modified for your purposes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

void find(char* path,char* file)
{
    static int found =0;
    HANDLE fh;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    fh=FindFirstFile(path,&wfd);
    if(fh)
    {
        if(strcmp(wfd.cFileName,file)==0)
        {
            path[strlen(path)-3]='\0';
            strcat(path,file);
            FindClose(fh);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            while(FindNextFile(fh,&wfd) && found ==0)
            {              
                if(strcmp(wfd.cFileName,file)==0)
                {
                    path[strlen(path)-3]='\0';
                    strcat(path,file);
                    FindClose(fh);
                    found =1;
                    return;
                }
                if(wfd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY &&
                    strcmp(wfd.cFileName,"..")!=0 && strcmp(wfd.cFileName,".")!=0)
                {
                    path[strlen(path)-3]='\0';
                    strcat(path,wfd.cFileName);
                    strcat(path,"\\*.*");
                    find(path,file);
                }
            }

            if(found==0)
                {
                for(i=strlen(path)-1;i>0;i--)
                {
                    if(j==1 && path[i]=='\\')
                    {
                        path[i]='\0';
                        strcat(path,"\\*.*");
                        break;
                    }
                    if(path[i]=='\\')
                        j=1;
                }
            }
        }
        FindClose(fh);
    }



}

int main()
{
    TCHAR path[512] = "C:\\*.*";
    find(path,"notepad.exe");
    printf("%s\n",path);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, but I don't know how I could edit it.
Please close this topic.

Comment: @Taco -  What do you mean you don't know how you could edit it?  and what do you mean close this topic?

Comment: I mean i don't know how to edit my code using code which you sent to me.

Comment: But I got the answer to my question and that's why the topic can be closed.

Comment: @Taco - Okay.  Actually, by accepting an answer, as you have done, indicates you have what you needed, and the topic has been _answered_.  Topics here are not typically closed unless they are determined to be not useful to future inquiries by other users asking the same question.