# Find file in the directory C

Tags: c, file, directory

How can I list one file from a folder using this code? 
I tried to add a variable containing the name of this file - to no avail.

```
void _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
   HANDLE hFind;
   if( argc != 2 )
   {
      _tprintf(TEXT("Usage: %s [target_file]\n"), a);
      return;
   }

   _tprintf (TEXT("Target file is %s\n"), argv[1]);
   hFind = FindFirstFile(argv[1], &FindFileData);
   if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      printf ("FindFirstFile failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
      return;
   }
   else
   {
      _tprintf (TEXT("The first file found is %s\n"),
                FindFileData.cFileName);
      FindClose(hFind);
   }
}
```

Comment: Use the Windows API functions  [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea).  There is [code here that answers your question using these.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60886619/645128)

Comment: FindFirstFile only finds one file using search criteria (eg. '\*file\*.txt` ) you provide, and  the directory path.  Test the first file using for example [strstr()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) to see if it is the right file.   If that first file does not happen to be the one you are looking for, then FindNextFile continues the search with the same search criteria.  Continue to  use`strstr()` to look for the specific file.